# Failed to open browser

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I want to open browser when I click a button on keyguard screen.

Here is my code

```
public static void startOpenQuotationUrl(Context context, String urlString) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
    Log.v(TAG, "context name:" + context.getClass().getSimpleName());
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(urlString));
    intent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_CREATE_NEW_TAB, context.getPackageName());
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

It is successful to open the browser if the browser is not alive.But it is failed when the browser process exists.

Here is part of my manifest

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:process="com.android.systemui"
    android:persistent="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true">

    <service android:name=".KeyguardService"
        android:exported="true" />
</application>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you explicitly set the activity as BROWSABLE in the intent-filter?

Comment: I tried it just now. It is Failed.

Comment: Ok I would try just creating a webview and loading the url directly from there if this is not working for you.

Comment: A browser chooser disappeared in a flash.